# Draw permanently on PGraphics (Processing)

Tags: image-processing, processing, pgraphics

I would like to create a brush for drawing on a PGraphics element with Processing. I would like past brush strokes to be visible. However, since the PGraphics element is loaded every frame, previous brush strokes disappear immediatly.

My idea was then to create PGraphics `pg` in setup(), make a copy of it in void(), alter the original graphic `pg` and update the copy at every frame. This produces a NullPointerException, most likely because `pg` is defined locally in setup().

This is what I have got so far:

PGraphics pg;
PFont font;

```
void setup (){
  font = createFont("Pano Bold Kopie.otf", 600);
  size(800, 800, P2D);
  pg = createGraphics(800, 800, P2D);
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);
  pg.fill(255);
  pg.textFont(font);
  pg.textSize(400);
  pg.pushMatrix();
  pg.translate(width/2, height/2-140);
  pg.textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  pg.text("a", 0 , 0);
  pg.popMatrix();
  pg.endDraw();
}

void draw () {
  copy(pg, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
  loop();
  int c;

  loadPixels();
  for (int x=0; x<width; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
      pg.pixels[mouseX+mouseY*width]=0;
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

My last idea, which I have not attempted to implement yet, is to append pixels which have been touched by the mouse to a list and to draw from this list each frame. But this seems quite complicated to me as it might result into super long arrays needing to be processed on top of the original image. So, I hope there is another way around!

EDIT: My goal is to create a smudge brush, hence a brush which kind of copies areas from one part of the image to other parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to manually copy pixels like that. The [PGraphics class](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PGraphics.html) extends `PImage`, which means you can simply render it with `image(pg,0,0);` for example.

The other thing you could do is an old trick to fade the background: instead of clearing pixels completely you can render a sketch size slightly opaque rectangle with no stroke.

Here's a quick proof of concept based on your code:

```
PFont font;
PGraphics pg;

void setup (){
  //font = createFont("Pano Bold Kopie.otf", 600);
  font = createFont("Verdana",600);

  size(800, 800, P2D);
  // clear main background once
  background(0);
  // prep fading background
  noStroke();
  // black fill with 10/255 transparnecy
  fill(0,10);

  pg = createGraphics(800, 800, P2D);
  pg.beginDraw();
  // leave the PGraphics instance transparent
  //pg.background(0);
  pg.fill(255);
  pg.textFont(font);
  pg.textSize(400);
  pg.pushMatrix();
  pg.translate(width/2, height/2-140);
  pg.textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  pg.text("a", 0 , 0);
  pg.popMatrix();
  pg.endDraw();
}

void draw () {
  // test with mouse pressed
  if(mousePressed){
    // slowly fade/clear the background by drawing a slightly opaque rectangle
    rect(0,0,width,height);
  }
  // don't clear the background, render the PGraphics layer directly
  image(pg, mouseX - pg.width / 2, mouseY - pg.height / 2);
}
```

If you hold the mouse pressed you can see the fade effect.
(changing transparency to 10 to a higher value with make the fade quicker)

**Update** To create a smudge brush you can still sample pixels and then manipulate the read colours to some degree. There are many ways to implement a smudge effect based on what you want to achieve visually.

Here's a very rough proof of concept:

```
PFont font;
PGraphics pg;

int pressX;
int pressY;

void setup (){
  //font = createFont("Pano Bold Kopie.otf", 600);
  font = createFont("Verdana",600);

  size(800, 800, P2D);
  // clear main background once
  background(0);
  // prep fading background
  noStroke();
  // black fill with 10/255 transparnecy
  fill(0,10);

  pg = createGraphics(800, 800, JAVA2D);
  pg.beginDraw();
  // leave the PGraphics instance transparent
  //pg.background(0);
  pg.fill(255);
  pg.noStroke();
  pg.textFont(font);
  pg.textSize(400);
  pg.pushMatrix();
  pg.translate(width/2, height/2-140);
  pg.textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  pg.text("a", 0 , 0);
  pg.popMatrix();
  pg.endDraw();
}

void draw () {
  image(pg,0,0);
}

void mousePressed(){
  pressX = mouseX;
  pressY = mouseY;
}

void mouseDragged(){
  // sample the colour where mouse was pressed
  color sample = pg.get(pressX,pressY);
  // calculate the distance from where the "smudge" started to where it is
  float distance = dist(pressX,pressY,mouseX,mouseY);
  // map this distance to transparency so the further the distance the less smudge (e.g. short distance, high alpha, large distnace, small alpha)
  float alpha = map(distance,0,30,255,0);
  // map distance to "brush size"
  float size = map(distance,0,30,30,0);
  // extract r,g,b values
  float r = red(sample);
  float g = green(sample);
  float b = blue(sample);
  // set new r,g,b,a values
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.fill(r,g,b,alpha);
  pg.ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,size,size);
  pg.endDraw();
}
```

As the comments mention, one idea is to sample colour on press then use the sample colour and fade it as your drag away from the source area. This shows simply reading a single pixel. You may want to experiment with sampling/reading more pixels (e.g. a rectangle or ellipse).

[image: smudge a demo]

Additionally, the code above isn't optimised.
A few things could be sped up a bit, like reading pixels, extracting colours, calculating distance, etc.

For example:

```
void mouseDragged(){
  // sample the colour where mouse was pressed
  color sample = pg.pixels[pressX + (pressY * pg.width)];
  // calculate the distance from where the "smudge" started to where it is (can use manual distance squared if this is too slow)
  float distance = dist(pressX,pressY,mouseX,mouseY);
  // map this distance to transparency so the further the distance the less smudge (e.g. short distance, high alpha, large distnace, small alpha)
  float alpha = map(distance,0,30,255,0);
  // map distance to "brush size"
  float size = map(distance,0,30,30,0);
  // extract r,g,b values
  int r = (sample >> 16) & 0xFF; // Like red(), but faster
  int g = (sample >> 8) & 0xFF;
  int b =  sample & 0xFF;
  // set new r,g,b,a values
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.fill(r,g,b,alpha);
  pg.ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,size,size);
  pg.endDraw();
}
```

The idea is to start simple with clear, readable code and only at the end, if needed look into optimisations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I realize that I missed an important aspect in the outline of my question. I am trying to create a smudge brush, hence a brush which kind of copies areas from one part of the image to other parts. This was also why I started the manually copying of pixels. So opacity is a useful hint in any case but if I would like to smudge the letter, I also need to stop the letter itself from rendering again and again. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I've updated my answer above with a basic approach to something like a smudge brush. Hopefully this gives you an idea of how take this further.

Comment: Thank you, that was super helpful! I think there is a long way of optimisation and learning for to go until I can create the brush I have in mind but your proposal is a great start!

Comment: Glad to help, sounds like a fun one! Though it may be overkill I'd also look at how Gimp or other opensource programs implement smudge. a bit of blur might help as well. Plenty of fun to be done :) enjoy!